# Find all lines between two patterns, EXCLUSIVE of the second pattern?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, perl

Consider that I have the file listed below.  I need to select all lines from every instance of the regex pattern `Word A` to **before** the regex pattern `Word D`.

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
Word E
Word F
Word G
Word A
Word H
Word I
Word D
Word J
Word A
Word K
Word D
Word L
Word M
Word A
Word D
```

Note the variable number of rows between `A` and `D`.  Sometimes, `D` is the very next row.  Here's what I need the output to be:

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word A
Word H
Word I
Word A
Word K
Word A
```

Can be done with awk, perl, python, or sed.  Doesn't matter as long as it's installed on the RHEL6 server where the file is.

Comment: What if the file contains 2 `Word D`s after `Word A` - stop at the first or the last one? What if there's `Word A` but no `Word D` - print to end of file or not? `Word D` without `Word A` - print from start of file? `OtherWord A` - should that match `Word A`? If `Word D` appears mid-line should the part of the line before it be printed? What if both exist on the same line?  etc., etc.....

Comment: See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for considerations when asking a pattern matching question on how to make your requirements clear.

Comment: @EdMorton "What if the file contains 2 Word Ds after Word A"?  Stop at the first one.

Comment: @EdMorton "What if there's Word A but no Word D - print to end of file or not?"  That's a *very* low probability occurrence.  Missing that last one is ok.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state your rainy-day requirements like that and include the rainy-day cases in your sample input/output so we have something to test a potential solution with. Regarding "That's a very low probability occurrence" - not handling those is where most software bugs show up.

Comment: @EdMorton "Word D without Word A - print from start of file?"  If there's no `Word A`, then there's no way to select all lines between `Word A` and `Word D`; Thus, no lines would be choses.  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @EdMorton "OtherWord A - should that match Word A? If Word D appears mid-line"  They're regex patterns, as mentioned in the question.  That should answer your question.

Comment: No, you aren't misunderstanding me. A potential solution could do something JUST on seeing `Word D` whether there was a previous `Word A` or not - that's one of the many common rainy-day failure points for solutions to problems like this if explicit requirements aren't stated and the situation doesn't exist in the sample input/output.

Comment: No, "they're regex patterns" doesn't answer that. Let's say your input contained `Word A\nfoo Word D\n` (i.e. ```foo ``` is on the same line as and preceding `Word A`) - the question of whether or not ```foo ``` should be printed has nothing to do with whether you want to match on a regexp or a string.

Comment: @EdMorton`Word D` is **a regex pattern**.  (Making that explicit has been the only edit to my question.)  Being a regex pattern means that "do something JUST on seeing `Word D`" won't trigger my real pattern.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. Maybe you mean "`Word A` is a regexp that has to match a full line of input" in which case you should include lines like `foo Word D` and `Word A foo` in your sample input/output to test a potential solution with. All of the answers you have so far that do regexp comparison would fail given a test case like that. Or maybe you mean that your users are expected to always use a regexp with star/end anchors like `^Word A$`, in which case say that in your question.

Comment: The thing is, with any pattern matching problem it's always FAR easier to match what you want than it is to not match similar text you don't want so it's important to think through and state what those rainy-day "similar text I don't want" cases are and how they should be handled, and include them in your sample input/output.

Comment: @EdMorton steeldriver's comment does what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU sed only:

```bash
sed '/Word A/!d;:1;n;/Word D/d;b1' file
```

In more complex cases - invalid blocks:

```bash
sed -n '/Word A/!b;:1;/Word A/h;n;/Word D/{g;p;d};H;b1' file
```

Answer (score 4):

Using AWK:

```
awk '/Word A/ { m = 1 } /Word D/ { m = 0 } m'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `awk` solution

```
awk \
  -vstart='Word A' \
  -vend='Word D' \
  '{
     if ($0==end  ) {flag=0;next};
     if ($0==start) {flag=1};
     if (flag==1) {print $0};
  }'
```

Only a minor change required for regex handling

```
awk \
  -vstart='Word[ ]A' \
  -vend='Word[ ]D' \
  '{
     if ($0 ~ end  ) {flag=0;next};
     if ($0 ~ start) {flag=1};
     if (flag==1) {print $0};
  }'
```

Comment: Close, but does not work for when `Word D` comes right after `Word A`.  Also, I apparently wasn't explicit enough when I wrote that it must work on patterns; they'll be simple regex patterns.

Comment: Worked in my tests where A and D and on consecutive lines eg https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7E8WyGGS0FBt6y4JLGoxFY9PL8oJVoh1lEdKpyalwIXdIEIqlcDCSDITFPQUDFQqFMAqlFQ0FSoTstJTLc1sM5LrSiptUZTAzYepsYQWRosYmsIlCsoyswrUVAxAMvWqnP9/w@yWMGRC0y5QChnLmRBJ5ggAA

Comment: If you have a requirement where matches can occur on the same line in the input, this is not clear from the question as posed, so please amend accordingly.

Comment: I worked around the situation where `Word D` is on the same line as `Word A` (which happens every time) with a sed substitution that adds "marker text" to the beginning of every `Word A` line.  Combined with @nezabudka's answer, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if / Word \h A / fff^ / Word \h D /;'  file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. It's an "operator-rich" language that features a powerful Regex engine. Above, the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags are used, in conjunction with Raku's sed-like `fff` "Flip-flop" operator.

Raku includes various 'flavors' of its sed-like `fff` infix operator, including `fff^`, `^fff` and even `^fff^`. While each Regex is recognized, the `^` caret indicates that recognized line should be dropped from the output:

Sample Input:

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word D
Word E
Word F
Word G
Word A
Word H
Word I
Word D
Word J
Word A
Word K
Word D
Word L
Word M
Word A
Word D
```

Sample Output:

```
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word A
Word H
Word I
Word A
Word K
Word A
```

The above code solves the OP's test case. But what if the `/start/` and `/stop/` Regexes are actually on the same line? For that problem you could try Raku's awk-like `ff` operator:

```
~$ echo 'AB\nCD\nEF' | raku -ne 'say $_ if /A/ ff /B/;'
AB
~$ echo 'AB\nCD\nEF' | raku -ne 'say $_ if /A/ ff /C/;'
AB
CD
```

As compared to Raku's sed-like `fff` operator:

```
~$ echo 'AB\nCD\nEF' | raku -ne 'say $_ if /A/ fff /B/;'
AB
CD
EF
~$ echo 'AB\nCD\nEF' | raku -ne 'say $_ if /A/ fff /C/;'
AB
CD
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/fff
https://docs.raku.org/routine/ff
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

TXR Lisp's [`awk`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-179D63DE) macro supports this directly; the [`rng`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-4000EC0B)  (range) operator has nine variants for various ways of excluding records from the start or end of a range:

```
$ txr -e '(awk ((rng- #/Word A/ #/Word D/)))' data
Word A
Word B
Word C
Word A
Word H
Word I
Word A
Word K
Word A
```

Also, unlike Awk's range operator, it combines with other operators. E.g. suppose you wanted to print records which are simultaneously in a `foo` to `bar` range, **and** in a `start` to `end` range, no matter how those kinds of ranges overlap in the data:

```
(awk ((and (rng #/foo/ #/bar/)
           (rng #/start/ #/end/))))
```

Comment: I'll have to take your word for it.

Comment: Never heard of TXR Lisp. Will have to investigate.

Comment: Your final example: tried similar with Raku (a.k.a Perl6) and it works! `raku -ne '.put if (/ A / fff / C /) & (/ B / fff / D /);'  file`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '
    $0 == "Word A" { f=1; rec=$0; next }
    { if ( $0 == "Word D" ) { print rec; f=0 } }
    f{rec = rec ORS $0}'

# For regex pattern
$ awk '          
    (/Word A/ && !/Word D/) { f=1; rec=$0; next }
    (/Word D/ && rec){ print rec; f=0; rec="" }
    f{rec = rec ORS $0}
'
```

If `Word D` matches `Word A` everytime, then the following command may be used.

```
$ awk '/Word A/,/Word D/ { if (!/Word D/) print }'
```

Answer (score -2):

`sed` lets one do arithmetic on line specifications:

```
sed -n -e '/Word A/,/Word D/-1p' The_File
```

Read `man sed`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported by GNU sed - [range addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses) only appear to allow *positive* offsets relative to the *start* of the range (like `/Word A/,+3p`).  However you could do `/Word A/,/Word D/{/Word D/!p}` I think.

Comment: Tested in GNU sed; does not work.

Comment: @steeldriver `sed -n -e '/Word A/,/Word D/{/Word D/!p}' The_file` works.  Make this an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: @RonJohn if you use range expressions then you end up having to specify the same regexp twice while if you use a flag you don't. That makes a flag solution better than a range solution. Sed doesn't have variables to use as flags but awk does.

Comment: Not my downvote by the way.